# Starcraft replay regex, bracket troubles

Tags: regex, rss, yahoo, yahoo-pipes

[2v2] race=[TPvZP] map=[Monlyth Ridge] players=[player 1(T)(w), player 2(P)(L) vs player3(Z)(W), player4(P)(W)] Length=[00-10-06]

Working in a Starcraft site for TheLittleOne (a pro player), I'm struggling to find the regex for the following situation. The [ brackets are causing the regex expression to be to long.

I want the following stings
EG)
The gametype: 2v2
The race: TPvZP
Map: Monlyth Ridge
Player1:Name
Player2:Name
Player3:Name
Player4:Name
Player1-4:Race (P,T,Z,R)
Player 1-4: Win (W,L)
Game Length: 10 Minutes 6 seconds.

I've searched S.O. for several days and I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Besides searching, what have you tried?

Comment: .*([^players]).*([^map]) That's the closest I've gotten.

Comment: .+?vs(.+?) = Separates the teams, but on team 2 I get the Length=[time], so I'm unsure as to how to end before length.

Comment: I suggest you read a good regex tutorial...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the string `[2v2] race=[TPvZP] map=[Monlyth Ridge] players=[player 1(T)(w), player 2(P)(L) vs player3(Z)(W), player4(P)(W)] Length=[00-10-06]`,

`~ ((\w*) \s*=\s*)? \[(.*?)\] ~ msx` will produce the following:

```
"" => 2v2
race => TPvZP
map => Monlyth Ridge
players => player 1(T)(w), player 2(P)(L) vs player3(Z)(W), player4(P)(W)
Length => 00-10-06
```

then applying `~ (.*?) \( (\w) \) \( (\w) \) \s* ,? \s* (vs)? ~ msx` on `players` should produce something like this:

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => T
        [1] => P
        [2] => Z
        [3] => P
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => w
        [1] => L
        [2] => W
        [3] => W
    )
```

which seems to be enough to make your desired output string.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up for me. And I bought a REGEX book recommended by a friend.